# How to get Host and Port configuration for Test Environment in Rspec 3.10 Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec2

Hi I have a controller file at `app/controllers/lti_controller.rb` and I need to add Test for the `POST #launch` endpoint which is defined as `/lti/launch` in `routes.rb` and working as intended.

### Problem

I need to send some data to the `/lti/launch` in the encoding format `x-www-form-urlencoded` and by using Net::HTTP I am doing that from the spec file.
But as Net::HTTP requires `host` and `port` for their operation and I have given `localhost:3000` as of now and which is going to the `development` environment.

### Question

1. How to access the host and port of the test environment in Rspec 3.10 such that I can pass them in spec file ?
2. Is there any way to use `post` '/lti/launch' , req.body : data in `x-www-form-urlencoded` format` ? and also get the host and port of the test environment ?

#### My Spec file

`spec/requests/lti_spec.rb`

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require "rails_helper"
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'

describe LtiController, type: :request do
    before do
        # shared keys for lms access
        @oauth_consumer_key_fromlms = 'some_keys'
        @oauth_shared_secret_fromlms = 'some_secrets'
    end

    describe "#launch" do        
        before do
            # creation of assignment and required users
            @mentor = FactoryBot.create(:user)
            @group = FactoryBot.create(:group, mentor: @mentor)
            @member = FactoryBot.create(:user)
            FactoryBot.create(:group_member, user: @member, group: @group)
            @assignment = FactoryBot.create(:assignment, group: @group, lti_consumer_key: @oauth_consumer_key_fromlms, lti_shared_secret: @oauth_shared_secret_fromlms, status: "open")
        end

        def launch_uri
            launch_url = "http://0.0.0.0:3000/lti/launch"
            URI(launch_url)
        end

        let(:parameters) {
            {
                'launch_url' => launch_uri().to_s,
                'user_id' => @member.id,
                'launch_presentation_return_url' => 'http://localhost:3000/tool_return',
                'lti_version' => 'LTI-1p0',
                'lti_message_type' => 'basic-lti-launch-request',
                'resource_link_id' => '88391-e1919-bb3456',
                'lis_person_contact_email_primary' => @member.email,
                'tool_consumer_info_product_family_code' => 'moodle',
                'context_title' => 'sample Course',
                'lis_outcome_service_url' => 'http://localhost:3000/grade_passback',
                'lis_result_sourcedid' => SecureRandom.hex(10)
            } 
        }

        def consumer_data(oauth_consumer_key_fromlms, oauth_shared_secret_fromlms, parameters)
            consumer = IMS::LTI::ToolConsumer.new(oauth_consumer_key_fromlms, oauth_shared_secret_fromlms, parameters)
            allow(consumer).to receive(:to_params).and_return(parameters)
            consumer.generate_launch_data
        end

        context "lti parameters are valid" do
            it "returns success if assignment key and secret are ok and group member is present" do
                data = consumer_data(@oauth_consumer_key_fromlms, @oauth_shared_secret_fromlms, parameters)
                response = Net::HTTP.post_form(launch_uri(), data)
                expect(response.code).to eq("200")
            end
        end

        
    end
end
```

#### My Controller file

`app/controllers/lti_controller.rb`

```
class LtiController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: :launch # for lti integration
  before_action :set_group_assignment, only: %i[launch]
  before_action :set_lti_params, only: %i[launch]
  after_action :allow_iframe_lti, only: %i[launch]
  
  def launch
    session[:is_lti]=true # the lti session starting
    require 'oauth/request_proxy/action_controller_request'

    if @assignment.blank?
      # if no assignment is found
      flash[:notice] = t("lti.launch.notice_no_assignment")
      render :launch_error, status: 401
      return
    end
    
    if @group.present? # if there is a valid group based for the lti_token_key
      @provider = IMS::LTI::ToolProvider.new(
        params[:oauth_consumer_key], # lms_oauth_consumer_key
        @assignment.lti_shared_secret, # the group's lti_token
        params
      )

      if !@provider.valid_request?(request) # checking the lti request from the lms end
        render :launch_error, status: 401
        return
      end

      lms_lti_host = URI.join @launch_url_from_lms, '/' # identifies the domain and saves in session
      session[:lms_domain]=lms_lti_host

      @user = User.find_by(email: @email_from_lms) # find user by matching email with circuitverse and lms 

      if @user.present? # user is present in cv 
        if @user.id == @group.mentor_id # user is teacher
          sign_in(@user) # passwordless sign_in the user as the authenticity is verified via lms
          lms_auth_success_notice = t("lti.launch.notice_lms_auth_success_teacher", email_from_lms: @email_from_lms, lms_type: @lms_type, course_title_from_lms: @course_title_from_lms)
          redirect_to group_assignment_path(@group, @assignment), notice: lms_auth_success_notice # if auth_success send to group page
        else
          user_in_group = GroupMember.find_by(user_id:@user.id,group_id:@group.id) # check if the user belongs to the cv group

          if user_in_group.present? # user is member of the group
            # render the button
            flash[:notice] =  t("lti.launch.notice_students_open_in_cv")
            create_project_if_student_present() # create project with lis_result_sourced_id for the student
            render :open_incv, status: 200

          else # user is not a member of the group
            # send the user an email
            flash[:notice] = t("lti.launch.notice_ask_teacher")
            render :launch_error, status: 401
          end 
        end
      else # no such user in circuitverse,showing a notice to create an account in cv
        flash[:notice] = t("lti.launch.notice_no_account_in_cv", email_from_lms: @email_from_lms )
        render :launch_error, status: 400
      end
    else # there is no valid group present for the lti_consumer_key
      flash[:notice] = t("lti.launch.notice_invalid_group")
      render :launch_error, status: 400
    end
  end

  def allow_iframe_lti
    return unless session[:is_lti]
    
    response.headers["X-FRAME-OPTIONS"] = "ALLOW-FROM #{session[:lms_domain]}"
  end

  def create_project_if_student_present
    @user = User.find_by(email: @email_from_lms)
    @project = Project.find_by(author_id: @user.id, assignment_id: @assignment.id) # find if the project is already present
    if @project.blank? # if not then create one
      @project = @user.projects.new
      @project.name = "#{@user.name}/#{@assignment.name}"
      @project.assignment_id = @assignment.id
      @project.project_access_type = "Private"
      @project.build_project_datum
      @project.lis_result_sourced_id = params[:lis_result_sourcedid] # this param is required for grade submission
      @project.save
    end
  end

  private

    def set_group_assignment # query db and check lms_oauth_consumer_key is equal to which assignment and find the group also
      @assignment = Assignment.find_by(lti_consumer_key: params[:oauth_consumer_key])
      if @assignment.present?
        @group =@assignment.group
      end
    end
    
    def set_lti_params # get some of the parameters from the lti request
      @email_from_lms = params[:lis_person_contact_email_primary] # the email from the LMS
      @lms_type = params[:tool_consumer_info_product_family_code] # type of lms like moodle/canvas
      @course_title_from_lms = params[:context_title] # the course titile from lms
      @launch_url_from_lms = params[:launch_presentation_return_url]
      session[:lis_outcome_service_url] = params[:lis_outcome_service_url] # requires for grade submission
      session[:oauth_consumer_key] = params[:oauth_consumer_key] # requires for grade submission
    end
end
```

#### Sample data needed to be sent

```
{"oauth_consumer_key"=>"some_keys", "oauth_signature_method"=>"HMAC-SHA1", "oauth_timestamp"=>"1627879512", "oauth_nonce"=>"Id3rLYZBqMvnRuSpisMEEgFkLFnkxZPS2oqoyBJZLM", "oauth_version"=>"1.0", "context_title"=>"sample Course", "launch_presentation_return_url"=>"http://localhost:3000/tool_return", "launch_url"=>"http://0.0.0.0:3000/lti/launch", "lis_outcome_service_url"=>"http://localhost:3000/grade_passback", "lis_person_contact_email_primary"=>"chung@towne-littel.org", "lis_result_sourcedid"=>"3e87e3aa8f5056260a12", "lti_message_type"=>"basic-lti-launch-request", "lti_version"=>"LTI-1p0", "resource_link_id"=>"88391-e1919-bb3456", "tool_consumer_info_product_family_code"=>"moodle", "user_id"=>"461", "oauth_signature"=>"lgsHKJxHolBU1rTZ5M9zXg688hU="}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Rspec, you can set the host before making the request.

```rb
it "returns success if assignment key and secret are ok and group member is present" do
  data = consumer_data(@oauth_consumer_key_fromlms, 
    @oauth_shared_secret_fromlms, parameters)
  host! "0.0.0.0:3000"
  response = Net::HTTP.post_form(launch_uri(), data)
  expect(response.code).to eq("200")
end
```

If you would like to set the host for all the specs, you can create a configuration like this:

```rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each, type: :request) do
    host! "0.0.0.0:3000"
  end
end
```

To post using the `x-www-form-urlencoded`, you can try this:

```rb
url = URI.parse(launch_uri())
data = consumer_data(@oauth_consumer_key_fromlms,@oauth_shared_secret_fromlms,parameters)

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.path)
request['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
request.body = URI.encode_www_form(data)
response = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) do |http|
  http.request(request)
end
```

Answer (score -3):

You don't need to know the host and port. And you should not perform the request directly with `Net::HTTP` manually. `get`/`post`/... helpers handle that. https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/5-0/docs/request-specs/request-spec

Comment: No I mean I need the host and port for a purpose, and is there any option to use post helper for sending in x-www-urlencoded format

Comment: You can set an appropriate header on the request. It is in the documentation, both in `rspec-rails` and in Rails [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#setting-headers-and-cgi-variables).

No, you don't need `Net::HTTP`. Use the Rails-provided `get` and `response`.

Comment: yah but I need the test enviornement's HOST and PORT , how to get them ?

Comment: Why do you need them?

Comment: I need them for a specific purpose see the code in `def launch_uri` there I need to give the host and port